# shared libraries in Xcode 6.3

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, shared-libraries

I am finding problems in dynamically loading boost::program_options.
I can build my project without errors both in Xcode and from command line.

If I build from command line, I can run my executable as I already exported the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH but in Xcode after compiling the project I cannot run it as I get the error

dyld: Library not loaded: libboost_program_options.dylib
Referenced from: 
Reason: image not found

How can I set Xcode running environment?

Comment: I'd expect Xcode to forward environment variables to child processes. Have you tried that?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: no I don't, and I haven't found a way to do it.

Comment: You do it the same way as you do it when starting your program from the commandline. You set it in the shell and export it, so that programs started from the shell inherit it.

Comment: Actually I found the place to set environment parameters in Xcode, it is hidden in the scheme section under product>scheme>edit scheme...